# Can't enable Salesforce Knowledge in my sandbox

Tags: knowledge, lightning-knowledge

I've read from [this](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/projects/build-a-community-with-knowledge-and-chat/steps/enable-and-configure-lightning-knowledge) trailhead how to enable Salesforce Knowledge. I don't see "Knowledge User" in my User record when I edit it.

[image]

My sandbox is Enterprise Edition. I've checked my User record in edit mode in both classic and lightning.

[image]

There are no Knowledge licenses available...

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can find *knowledge user* checkbox in user record like below image.

[image]

Also check feature licenses under company information:

[image]

Comment: checkout my updated post with screenshots.

Comment: @TylerZika Can you check your production org feature licenses

Comment: it's exactly the same as my sandbox screenshot. Knowledge User is not in the list.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know which cloud you are using but please see the comments below.

> Salesforce Knowledge is available in Performance and Developer
>   Editions and in Unlimited Edition with the Service Cloud.
>
> Salesforce Knowledge is available for an **additional cost** in:
>   Professional, **Enterprise**, and Unlimited Editions.

Then you need follow steps;

Did you enable Lightning Knowledge ?

1. From Salesforce Classic Setup, enter Knowledge in the Quick Find box
   and click **Knowledge Settings**.
   enter code here
2. If you’re new to Knowledge, enable Knowledge in Salesforce Classic by selecting **Yes** and clicking **Enable Salesforce Knowledge**.
3. On the Knowledge Settings page, click **Edit**.
4. Select **Enable Lightning Knowledge**.
5. Click **Save**.

After Lightning Knowledge is enabled, the node **Knowledge Object Setup** appears. This is where you control your Lightning Knowledge settings and page layouts.

Regards,

Comment: Did you read my post? I don't have access to knowledge via Setup. I go to my user record and there isn't even a check to make me a knowledge user.

Comment: Please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like it's an Add-On, so not all orgs would have it unless paid for
Ref: [salesforce knowledge and user licenses](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/70003/salesforce-knowledge-and-user-licenses)